# Create iOS Tab bar dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I want to create tab bar dynamically based on server response. Tab count will change every time. And how to design the views all view have the same design only data will change

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: i have tried the static tabs. i want to build dynamic tabs. So i need the logic for building dynamic tabs. i am new to ios development.

Comment: @Dhinakaran did you found any solution on dynamic tabs

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have  vc1,vc2,vc3

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2,vc3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate class for tab bar controller. Create a method there which must return tab bar controller.

In the method, pass an array, on each index it will contains the tab bar name, image, selected image, view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make your server call BEFORE you set up the view controller. If it is your first view, you will need to do this in viewdidload and perhaps set up an activity indicator. If not you need to have some sort of loading screen / make your call in the immediately prior to your tabBar.

Answer (score 0):

Put This Method in Utilities Class :

```
class func setupTabBarController(tabbarController: UITabBarController) {


let hOmeVC = HomePageViewController()
let skriblBoxVC = MySkribViewController()
let searchVC = SearchViewController()

tabbarController.tabBar.isExclusiveTouch = true
tabbarController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
// Creating navigation Controller and putting them in tabBarController because without it we will not be able to push viewController

let homeNavigationController = UINavigationController()
let skriblBoxNavigationController = UINavigationController()
let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController()



tabbarController.viewControllers = []
tabbarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false

tabbarController.viewControllers = [homeNavigationController, skriblBoxNavigationController, searchNavigationController]

tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0








tabbarController.tabBar.items![0].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_home")
tabbarController.tabBar.items![1].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_box")

tabbarController.tabBar.items![SBModules.SEARCH.rawValue].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_search")

tabbarController.tabBar.items![2].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_cart")



tabbarController.tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_home_selected")

tabbarController.tabBar.items![1].selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_box_selected")

tabbarController.tabBar.items![2].selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tab_search_selected")

tabbarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

tabbarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.tabBarBadgeColorWithAlpha()

tabbarController.tabBar.itemPositioning = .automatic

tabbarController.tabBar.itemSpacing = 2.0

tabbarController.tabBarItem.title = nil

if let items = tabbarController.tabBar.items {
    for item in items {
        item.title = ""
        item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
    }
}

}
```

and class this method form viewController
Like

```
let tabbarController = UITabBarController()

 func loadHomePage() {
Utilities.setupTabBarController(tabbarController:      self.tabbarController)
self.updateBadgeValueToCart()
self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabbarController
}
```